# nodejs http_outgoing crash with pastebin API

Tags: node.js, pastebin

I wrote a node app that does next to other cool stuff it also gives out a link to a pastebin that the app created from a txt file.

It works perfectly on my local macbook on OS X. But on my debian server that I rented this is what shows up when someone requests the link to the pastebin/requests that the app creates a pastebin

Edit: I had this working previously on my server aswell. Now I just re-arranged some code in seperate modules like connection.js, database.js and such

I replaced the pastebin module path with #pastebin# if it's needed I'll readd them. But all of them linked to things in pastebin-js/node_modules/request/request.js

This is the library I used for pastebin: https://github.com/j3lte/pastebin-js

```
_http_outgoing.js:339
        throw new TypeError(
        ^

    TypeError: Header name must be a valid HTTP Token ["Cache-Control:"]
        at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:339:11)
        at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:86:14)
        at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
        at Request.start (#pastebin#)
        at Request.write (#pastebin#)
        at end (#pastebin#)
        at #pastebin#
        at doNTCallback0 (node.js:428:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:357:13)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i guess I found my problem.

I had to upgrade node on my server since the syntax with module.exports and multiple exports was unknown there for some reason.

After 5.0 was to high it seems I downgraded to v4.2.1 now and it works great.

Comment: Saved me some time. I wasted lot of time trying to find the issue

Comment: glad to help, i hate when people find the answer to their problem. Before someone answers and then they don't post it...

Comment: I had a similar issue. v0.12.2 worked for me:  TypeError: Header name must be a valid HTTP Token ["set-token "]

Answer (score 1):

I got here from an unrelated `Header name must be a valid HTTP Token` search. My issue was I was trying to use this:

```
res.setHeader("Content-disposition: attachment; filename="+filename);
```

But after a certain version of express, you have to do it like this:

```
res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename);
```

The difference is the second one uses two args (name & value), where the first one is just one long string.

Comment: Very helpful analysis - in my case it was res.set() rather than res.setHeader(), but definitely the same issue with the single-argument call no longer working, fixed by replacing it with a 2-arg call.